# How to view IndexedDB content in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, indexeddb

I am fairly new to writing code, but I played around with some chrome apps which use WebSQL for DB. I decided to learn IndexedDB, but needed something more visual, to help me out. WebSQL database entries can be easily seen in in resources tab in "debugger", but indexedDB database is not shown there.

Chrome is v17, OS Ubuntu 11.10

Is there a workaround for this( plugin or anything else) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use Chromium or the dev channel of Chrome you can enable an experimental Dev Tools feature to surface IndexedDB in the Resources panel.

https://plus.google.com/u/0/100132233764003563318/posts/7pbJUZCGk8U

Comment: I tried with a Chromium 19 version for download 21.03.2012 for Linux. Even though I enabled IndexedDB, and it shows in resources, I see no entries. Even thoug the example I am trying is working. I try with the code, published here  http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/indexeddb/todo/ As far as I know, indexedDB has been changed, so that might also be the case

Comment: It is "Chromium 19.0.1077.0 custom", to be exact, dont know why it is "custom", just unzipped, run and changed some settings( enabled IndexedDB)

Comment: Same thing in 20.0.1105.0 canary - can see IndexedDB in resources and can see object stores but can't see any data

Comment: I can see data in the Dev Tools Resources panel in Chrome 21.0.1180.89 for http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/indexeddb/todo/

Comment: IndexedDB support in Chrome should be much much better now.

Comment: In current versions of Chrome (56-58) this is now under `Application / IndexedDB`

Comment: The link is no longer available.

Answer (score 3):

In chrome, click on developer tools or use ctr+shift+I
Click on the application menu
Right click on IndexDB
Click Refresh IndexDB
Then you will see your database content.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is 10 years old, mentioning experimental DevTools. So, I decided to rewrite answer.

- In Chrome, press F12 or click application menu > More Tools > Developer Tools to open Chrome Developer tools.
- Go to Application tab.
- On the menu left, expand IndexedDb under Storage section and you will see your IndexedDb content.

[image]